# how to log asynchronously in a heavily multithreaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, asynchronous, locking

I am trying to to log asynchronously in a heavily multi-threaded environment in java on linux platform.what would be a suitable data structure(lock-free) to bring in low thread contention? 
I need to log GBs of messages. I need to do it in async/lock-free manner so I don't kill performance on the main logic(the code that invokes the logger apis).

Comment: In which language? platform? etc...

Comment: A concurrent queue (lock-free or not) into which all threads can write messages, and a dedicated thread that reads the queue and writes to file. Unless you're writing many thousands of log entries per second, the existence of a lock just isn't going to matter. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8736438/56778

Answer (score 2):

Logback has an AsyncAppender that might meet your needs.

Comment: I assume this is not lock free.

Comment: No, but anything that does concurrent writing to an underlying filesystem will have to have locking at some point, since you'd otherwise end up with scrambled log lines.

Comment: @Visage "... end up with scrambled log lines ..." - not if you log to multiple files, one file for each thread.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is to write into multiple files - one for each thread.

Make sure you put timestamps at the start of each record, so it is easier to merge them into a single log file.

example unix command:

```
cat *.log | sort | less
```

But for a better / more useful answer you do need to clarify your question by adding a lot more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Java Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle), mostly because I wrote it but I suggest it here because you can write lock free and garbage free logging with a minimum of OS calls.  This requires one log per thread, but you will have kept these to a minimum already I assume.

I have used this library to write 1 GB/second from a two threads.  You may find having more threads will not help as much as you think if logging is a bottle neck for you.

BTW: You have given me an idea of how the log can be updated from multiple threads/processes, but it will take a while to implement and test.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce contention, you can first put log messages in a buffer, private to each thread. When the buffer is full, put it in a queue handled by a separate log thread, which then merges messages from different threads and writes them to a file. Note, you need that separate thread in any case, in order not to slowdown the working threads when the next buffer is to be written on disk.

Answer (score 0):

It is *impossible* to avoid queue contention as your logging thread will most likely log faster than your writer (disk i/o) thread can keep up, but with some smart wait strategies and thread pinning you can minimize latency and maximize throughput.

Take a look on [CoralLog](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/category/corallog/) developed by Coral Blocks (with which I am affiliated) which uses a [lock-free queue](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/category/coralqueue/) and can log a 64-byte message in 52 nanoseconds on average. It is capable of writing more than 5 million messages per second.